# PostgreSQL combine tables with one to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to determine the best method to do the following (even though I know how to easily accomplish this with server side code such as PHP, I want to only use postgreSQL if possible).

I have a table that lists the quantity of all the company's current customer ordered items and the date at which they are due to be delivered. For example:

```
Top Level Item, Quantity, Delivery Date
top_item_1, 5, 20140205
top_item_2, 10, 20140215
etc...
```

I have another table that has a list of top level items (items that would be ordered by a customer) and the corresponding component we need to buy to make that item and the quantity of the bought component. For example:

```
Top Level Item, Component, Quantity
top_item_1, component_1, 1
top_item_1, component_2, 4
top_item_1, component_3, 2
top_item_2, component_1, 2
top_item_2, component_4, 1
etc...
```

Now my question is how do i combine these tables such that I can get a list of all the required buy items for the current customer orders, when they are due, and how many are needed at that due date. For example:

```
Component, Quantity, Delivery Date
component_1, 5, 20140205
component_2, 20, 20140205
component_3, 10, 20140205
component_1, 20, 20140215
component_4, 10, 20140215
etc...
```

I apologize for the long winded question.  Any help in the above would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
~Daniel

Comment: The term you want to search for is "SQL JOIN".  Any good SQL tutorial will cover it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describes requires `join`ing the two tables:

```
SELECT c.component, c.quantity * qli.quantity AS qunatity, delivery_date
FROM   coponnets c
JOIN   top_level_items tli ON c.top_level_item = tli.top_level_item
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bca70/4

```
select p.component
     , o.delivery_date
     , sum(o.quantity * p.ratio) as quantity
from orders o
     inner join pack_items p on o.item = p.item
group by p.component, o.delivery_date
order by o.delivery_date, p.component
```